# Cython segfault when using inheritance and wrong parameter name in constructor

Tags: python, cython

I've encountered a series of strange segmentation faults in Cython related to inheritance.

The following minimal example illustrates this:

buffer.pxd

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint16_t, uint32_t
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_RawCalloc,PyMem_RawFree

cdef class PixelBase:
    pass
        
cdef class PixelBuffer(PixelBase):
    cdef:
        uint16_t* value

    cdef void allocate(self, uint32_t len)
    cdef void deallocate(self)
```

buffer.pyx

```
cdef class PixelBase:
    def __cinit__(self, uint32_t buf_len = 100):
        pass

    def __init__(self, uint32_t buf_len  = 100):
        pass


cdef class PixelBuffer(PixelBase):

    def __cinit__(self, uint32_t buf_len = 100):
        self.allocate(buf_len)

    def __init__(self, uint32_t buf_len = 100):
        super().__init__(buf_len)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.deallocate()

    cdef void allocate(self, uint32_t buf_len): 
        self.value = <uint16_t*> PyMem_RawCalloc(1, buf_len * sizeof(uint16_t))

    cdef void deallocate(self): 
        PyMem_RawFree(self.value)
```

If I cythonize it

```
cythonize -i buffer.pyx
```

and run a test with a **wrong** parameter name

```
from src.buffer import PixelBuffer

buffer = PixelBuffer(wrong_parameter_name=10)
```

then it segfaults (no exception is raised). With inheritance removed (PixelBuffer not a subclass of PixelBase), a proper exception is thrown.

I have encountered similar segfault problems related to inheritance and using properties and I am trying to figure out whether my inheritance implementation is fundamentally wrong.

Could anyone comment whether there is a fundamental error in the way I inherit PixelBuffer from PixelBase?

---

Python Version 3.11.4, Cython Version 3.0.2

Comment: This looks like a bug report rather than a question: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: The issue has to do with using a `cdef`-function in the destructor. The internal "vtable" for the class that tells it where `deallocate` is hasn't been set up at the point the constructor fails. Unfortunately that probably isn't easy to fix, but it's probably wrong that it crashes

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense! Thank you very much! By removing the function call and directly execute PyMem_RawFree, the problem is solved.

Comment: Still think it's worth a bug report if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is raised in the `__cinit__` of the superclass, the `__dealloc__` of the subclass will then be executed. If there is an instance C method called in the `__dealloc__` of the subclass, a bug will occur because the C method is not set up correctly in the meantime. (See below)

```
%%cython

cdef class PixelBase:
    def __cinit__(self, int buf_len = 100):
        raise Exception()

cdef class PixelBuffer(PixelBase):

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.abcd() #crashed
        
    cdef void abcd(self):
        pass
```

Moreover, it is not recommended to define instance C methods that are called specifically in `__init__`, `__cinit__`, `__dealloc__`, `__del__` of cdef classes because that provides minimal or no performance gain. A reusable piece of codes could be defined in cdef methods outside a class or wrapped by `@staticmethod` while inside a cdef class, which will be sufficient for most of the purposes when trying to speed up.

```
%%cython

cdef class PixelBase:
    def __cinit__(self, int buf_len = 100):
        raise Exception()

cdef class PixelBuffer(PixelBase):
    
    def __dealloc__(self):
        PixelBuffer.abcd(self) #no problem, the exception will be raised as expected

    @staticmethod
    cdef void abcd(PixelBuffer a):
        pass
```